# Adding additional blank lines in Minted

Tags: minted, python

I currently have two minted environments in each their minipage environment, so that they can be situated next to each other:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}

\begin{python}
  from pycsp_import import *

  @process
  def producer(cout):
    for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
      cout(i)
    retire(cout)

  @process
  def worker(cin):
    while True:
      print cin()

  c = Channel()

  Parallel(
    producer(-c),
    worker(+c)
  )
\end{python}

\end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}

\begin{python}
  1
  2
  3
  4
  Exception













  .
\end{python}

\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the need of the `.`. Can I somehow tell minted that there should be 19 lines, so that the two python environments are the same height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this you have to change the compilation by `pygmentize`. The required option is `stripnl`. For more details see: [Available lexers](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/)

To set the option to the run you have to change the internal definition:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\minted@pygmentize[2][\jobname.pyg]{
  \def\minted@cmd{pygmentize -l #2 -f latex -F tokenmerge
    \minted@opt{gobble} \minted@opt{texcl} \minted@opt{mathescape}
    \minted@opt{startinline} \minted@opt{funcnamehighlighting}
    \minted@opt{linenos} -P "verboptions=\minted@opt{extra}"
    -O stripnl=false -o \jobname.out.pyg #1}
  \immediate\write18{\minted@cmd}
  % For debugging, uncomment:
  %\immediate\typeout{\minted@cmd}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}
   {}
   {\begin{minted@colorbg}{\minted@opt@bgcolor}}
  \input{\jobname.out.pyg}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\minted@opt@bgcolor}{}}
   {}
   {\end{minted@colorbg}}
  \DeleteFile{\jobname.out.pyg}}
\makeatother
```

However this influence all compilation by `pygmentize`. To avoid this you can declare a new option.

[image]

Comment: you are a god amongst men! It works just as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Minted 2.1 has a `stripnl` option, you can set to false:

```
\begin{minted}[stripnl=false]{bash}
    exit
\end{minted}
```

Comment: `v2.6` the default for `stripnl` is now `false`, so that original code is preserved
exactly by default

Answer (score 4):

If you used

```
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
                 %%%
```

they would line up on the first line even if different sizes/

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer using `stripnl` did not work for me unfortunately. While `[t]` option for `minipage` makes them line up at the first line (see answer above), my code blocks were colored so it still looked ugly.

I found a workaround using the minted option `escapeinside` in combination with `\phantom`. Just put the escaped `\phantom` command so the line numbers add up (larger minted block has three lines here so phantom goes on third line of shorter block).

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth} % first minipage
\centering
\begin{minted}{python}
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth} % second minipage
\centering
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{python}
a = 1

|\phantom|
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```